# Why does `su` keep asking me password

Tags: linux, oracle, shell, su

I wanted to get the value of environment variable `ORACLE_HOME` as `root`, I've run the command `su - oracle -c 'echo $ORACLE_HOME'`, then shell has asked me for password, I have typed the password of user `oracle`, the password was correct, but it has asked again.

```
[root@localhost ~]# su - oracle -c 'echo $ORACLE_HOME'
Password:
Password:
Password:
Password:
... ...
... ... again and again ... ...
```

Then I have tried a simple command `su - oracle -c 'ls'`, still the same problem. However, if I simply press ENTER without typing anything, I've got:

```
su: incorrect password
DB  Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music  oradiag_oracle  oraInventory  Pictures  Public  Templates  Videos
```

It has told me that the password was incorrect (I'm pretty sure that I've typed the right password), but the command was executed, weired.

I have tried this command on an other Oracle server, the command can be executed without any problem, and I didn't even have to enter password, I could get the value of `ORACLE_HOME`.

I'd like to know what might be the cause of this problem. Thanks.

**Update 1**

I've tried the command on other PCs, it worked.
Thus, I think this might be a system configuration problem, maybe the entire environment was not correctly installed.

Still, I'd like to figure out what is wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong.  Try `su -c 'echo $ORACLE_HOME' - oracle`

Comment: @vesontio sounds like your PAM configuration is hosed

Comment: Heu ... maybe, I've never encountered a such problem, sounds like I have to reinstall the machine XD

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason for the problem in my system.

That's apparently how the `PAM` (Pluggable Authentication Module) is configured to be in my system (for security, probably).

I changed it by opening the file **`/etc/pam.d/su`** and modifying line `4` (*one that implicitly trusts all users in wheel group*).

**I don't know how it changes for system security, so use it at your own risk**

Maybe someone more knowledgable can help me understand this better, but as of now this is the solution I have found.

```
   1   │ #%PAM-1.0
   2   │ auth        sufficient  pam_rootok.so
   3   │ # Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
   4   │ #auth        sufficient  pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
   5   │ # Uncomment the following line to require a user to be in the "wheel" group.
   6   │ #auth       required    pam_wheel.so use_uid
   7   │ auth        substack    system-auth
   8   │ auth        include     postlogin
   9   │ account     sufficient  pam_succeed_if.so uid = 0 use_uid quiet
  10   │ account     include     system-auth
  11   │ password    include     system-auth
  12   │ session     include     system-auth
  13   │ session     include     postlogin
  14   │ session     optional    pam_xauth.so
```

I'm guessing this helps you on this? I don't have much idea on how this works, other than the fact that after doing this, my problems were gone.